# Calculate distanceTo between points consecutively and use an update cursor to fill in a new field in an attribute tablea

Tags: distance, cursor

I have a shapefile that I need to update with the distance between its points in the order they appear in the attribute table. I've been instructed to do this by using an Update Cursor and the DistanceTo geometry function. I'm struggling with what to put in my for-loop to update the table.

Here is what I have so far:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_table=filename, 
                       field_names=['SHAPE@', 'distance']) as updater:
    item = next(updater)
    previous = item
    for row in updater:
        distance = arcpy.Geometry.distanceTo('SHAPE@', item)
        updater.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: I am guessing you are getting an error.  If so, what is the error and traceback.  If the code is working and giving unexpected results, what are you getting and what were you expecting?

Comment: Hi! Here's the error I'm getting: 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_arc_object'

Comment: Please update the question with the information instead of putting it in a comment, and include the traceback with the error.

Comment: I need to frame-challenge here. Depending on the order retrieved in a query is risky without an ORDER BY, and ORDER BY is silently ignored by some data types.  This results in a Question for which the "correct"" answer is not always applicable to future cases.  Your code fails because you don't use the objects returned and instead try to use a class as if it were an instance..